# what is the name of this operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let's say I have some map $f$ that'll take a tuple with element types $A, B$ and $C$ to some type $T$

$f (x,y,z): A \times B \times C \rightarrow T$

and then say we have a map $g$, that takes an element $A$ and returns a map $h$, which takes a tuple of $B$ and $C$ to the same $T$.

$g (x): A \rightarrow \{h (y,z): B \times C \rightarrow T\}$

and let $f(x,y,z) = g(x)(y,z)$ for all $(x,y,z)$ in $A \times B \times C$

What's the name of the relationship $g$ has to $f$, or the name of the operation that produces $g$ from $f$? What sort of a thing is it?

I think it might be a lift but I'm not sure if I've understood what a lift is.

Comment: It's called currying.

Comment: I considered currying but I'm not sure that it is helpful in my specific case. I may be wrong, here's my thinking: The act of combining $f$ and $x$ to produce $h$ would be currying, so $h$ would be the curried form of $f$, so what is $g$? What do I call it, if I need to refer to the thing to which I pass an $x$ to receive an $h$, as its own entity? (a currier, I suppose)

Comment: On rereading the way I phrased my question, I'd call that a correct answer, though. I asked about the operation even though its $g$ that I'm really interested in. So anyway if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: After getting an answer to a rephrased question I realized that currying is indeed the answer I was looking for all along, I was just confusing currying with partial application.